# How to generate android apk with Prebop using Ant

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, preprocessor

I'm working on an Android project that need multiple versions from the same codebase (e.g. Lite/Pro) but Java doesn't allow preprocessing directives. A search on Google only throws this [this](http://boldinventions.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=81%3ajavapreprocessorusingeclipse&catid=34%3acategory-electronics-articles&Itemid=53) tutorial about the Prebop preprocessor. The problem is that the tutorial is not for Android and I don't know how to generate the apk after compile given an specific version. This is the ant code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Hello" default="compile" basedir=".">
    <property file="local.properties" />
    <property file="ant.properties" />
    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />
    <property name="android-home" value="../android-sdks" />
    <property name="android-version" value="3" />
    <property name="android-platform-specific" value="${android-home}/platforms/android-${android-version}" />
    <property name="android-jar" value="${android-platform-specific}/android.jar" />
    <property name="android-tools" value="${android-home}/platform-tools" />
    <property name="resource-folder" value="res" />
    <property name="gen-folder" value="gen" />

    <property name="src" location="src" />

    <property name="tmpfolder" value="/tmp/Hello" />
    <property name="src_lite" value="${tmpfolder}/src_lite"/>
    <property name="src_pro" value="${tmpfolder}/src_pro"/>   

    <property name="build" location="bin" />
    <property name="build_lite" value="${build}/lite"/>
    <property name="build_pro" value="${build}/pro"/>   

    <property name="out-folder" value="${build_lite}" />
    <property name="dex-file" value="classes.dex" />
    <property name="intermediate-dex" value="${out-folder}/${dex-file}" />
    <property name="external-libs-folder" value="bin/lite" />
    <property name="out-classes" value="${out-folder}/classes" />
    <property name="out-classes-location" value="./${out-classes}"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${tmpfolder}" />
        <delete dir="${build}" />
    </target>

    <target name="makedir">
        <mkdir dir="${src_lite}" />
        <mkdir dir="${src_pro}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build_lite}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build_pro}" />
    </target>

    <target name="resource-src" depends="makedir">
        <echo>Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...</echo>
        <exec executable="${android-tools}/aapt.exe" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="package" />
            <arg value="-m" />
            <arg value="-J" />
            <arg path="${gen-folder}" />
            <arg value="-M" />
            <arg path="AndroidManifest.xml" />
            <arg value="-S" />
            <arg path="${resource-folder}" />
            <arg value="-I" />
            <arg path="${android-jar}" />
            <arg value="--custom-package" />
            <arg value="com.pack.name" />
        </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="copysource">
        <copy todir="${src_lite}"><fileset dir="src" /></copy>
        <copy todir="${src_pro}"><fileset dir="src" /></copy>
    </target>

    <target name="splitsource"  description="preprocessor">
        <preprocess indir="${src}" outdir="${src_lite}" out="replace">
            <var name="pro" value="false"/>
            <filetype commentend="*/" commentbegin="/*" extensions="java"/>
        </preprocess>
        <preprocess indir="${src}" outdir="${src_pro}" out="replace">
            <var name="pro" value="true"/>
            <filetype commentend="*/" commentbegin="/*" extensions="java"/>
        </preprocess>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="makedir, copysource">
        <javac srcdir="${src_lite}" destdir="${build_lite}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath>
                <path id="application" location="${android-jar}"/>
                <path id="application" location="src" />
                <path id="application" location="res" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
        <javac srcdir="${src_pro}" destdir="${build_pro}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath>
                <path id="application" location="${android-jar}"/>
                <path id="application" location="src" />
                <path id="application" location="res" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
</project>
```

I hope someone can give me directions because is quite frustrating develop with multiple API's on Android.

Answer (score 2):

You should (at least) add "splitsource" dependency to "compile" target instead "copysource", so class files are generated with pre-processed java ones.

Answer (score -1):

In order to build android in command-line, you should follow below steps;

First create an android project;

```
PATH_TO_SDK/android create project -n NAME -p PATH -k PACKAGE -a ACTIVITY -t TARGET_ID
```

NAME: your project name
PATH: your project path
PACKAGE: your project package ( e.g. com.example )
ACTIVITY: your main activity 
TARGET_ID: your target SDK 's id

Then you can build with ant like below;

```
ant release
```

or

```
ant PATH/build.xml release
```

( NOTE: you can make arrangement you want in build.xml )

Your project should be builded successfully if your project doesn't have an error.

Now, you can see the debug apk files in the bin/ directory.

If you make release build, you should use jarsigner to sign your project like below;

```
jarsigner -verbose -storepass PASS -keypass KEY_PASS -keystore KEY_STORE_PATH PROJECT_PATH/bin/PROJECT_NAME-release-unsigned.apk YOUR_KEY_STORE_FILE
```

Then verify your .apk file;

```
jarsigner -verbose -verify PROJECT_PATH/bin/PROJECT_NAME-release-unsigned.apk
```

Finally, you are able to make final release apk file;

```
ANDROID_SDK_PATH/zipalign 4 PROJECT_PATH/bin/PROJECT_NAME-release-unsigned.apk PROJECT_PATH/bin/PROJECT_NAME-release.apk
```

Your apk is ready to release here;

**PROJECT_PATH/bin/PROJECT_NAME-release.apk**